# Creating an interactive menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to create an interactive menu that does a couple of different things.
The general layout will be as follows:

|  button 1  |   button 2   |   button 3    |   button 4   |
| the above buttons will need to display a unique menu each here|

A box (div) below the menus will display content based on the combination of buttons selected above

I understand how to create the lists with clickable links. What I don't understand is how to utilize a script to tie everything together and make it interact in the aforementioned fashion

Comment: Show what code you have tried so far.

Comment: conceptually speaking, you're referring to what I understand to be flag  enumeration.. which we use bitwise operations on the values... Javascript doesn't support flag enumeration as a type, so it's going to be a matter of associating a value (represented as 2^n, where n is the position) to a field/element/object..

Comment: All i have thus far is the list <ul>
  <li><a href="#">HRX</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HRR</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HRS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HRC</a></li>
</ul>  I was unsure how to proceed to link these items to another menu that displays when you click an option. and then from there display content based on two selections

Comment: i had initially assumed to display another menu based on a selection i would first create all iteration of list combinations and then use if/else statements to display the proper secondary menu. then when the secondary option is chosen it would display some information about the desired product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're really supposed to ask questions in the context of an issue you're having with your existing code and functionality.. not a design feature or tutorial based question.

With that said, I'm going to provide an answer and code sample to this because I like to introduce developers (and more particular, DBAs) to bitwise operations. As we can represent state better this way..

That is not to say that my following code is best practice or optimal.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-bit");
var sections = document.querySelectorAll("section[data-bit]");
var menuvalue = 0; //0 displays nothing
var clrBtn = document.querySelector("button#none");


clrBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    menuvalue = 0;
    setDisplay();
});

for(var i = 0, max = buttons.length; i < max ; i++)
{
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", changeValue.bind(null, Math.pow(2, i)));
}

function changeValue(value) {
    console.log(value);
    menuvalue ^= value; //XOR operation assignment  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/06f6ta51(v=vs.94).aspx)
    console.log(menuvalue);
    setDisplay();
}

function setDisplay()  {
    for (var i = 0, max = sections.length; i < max; i++)
    {
        
        console.log("section: %o, menuvalue: %o, result: %o", Math.pow(2, i), menuvalue, (Math.pow(2, i) & menuvalue));
        sections[i].style.display = (Math.pow(2, i) & menuvalue) > 0 ? "block" : "none";      
    }
}
```

```css
section {
  display:none;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  border:0.1em outset whitesmoke;
  line-height:1.25em;
  padding:2em;
  }

section[data-bit] {
  display:none;
  }


button.check {
  border:0.1em inset whitesmoke;
  background-color:whitesmoke;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
<button id="none">None</button>
<button data-bit="0">Menu Item 1</button>
<button data-bit="1">Menu Item 2</button>
<button data-bit="2">Menu Item 3</button>
<button data-bit="4">Menu Item 4</button>
<button data-bit="8">Menu Item 5</button>
</nav>

<section class="empty">
This is either the default value, displaying no menu items.. or you could hide this and display nothing!
</section>
<section data-bit="0">
This is the contents of Menu Item 1
</section>
<section data-bit="1">
This is the contents of Menu Item 2
</section>
<section data-bit="2">
This is the contents of Menu Item 3
</section>
<section data-bit="4">
This is the contents of Menu Item 4
</section>
<section data-bit="8">
This is the contents of Menu Item 5
</section>
```

### JsFiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bcaswell/0897rw76/2/)

#### Handling Combinations: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bcaswell/0897rw76/1/)

Comment: the **data attributes** (`data-bit`) are superfluous (providing no functional purpose) beyond marking a particular element to be queried based on the existence of the attribute.. you can, however, query against them like so: `section[data-bit="4"] { background-color:green; }` in css, AND `document.querySelector('section[data-bit="4"]')` should return the element.

Comment: well thank you very much for that. I appreciate the insight and being pointed in the right direction which was my ultimate goal. not neccessarily having the code developed for me :)

Comment: I added a link to a jsfiddle that handles the combinations, for I reread your question and it appeared they may be more inline with what you asking... it is a simple matter of adding up the values and using it as an index..